# Unable to Empty a div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jQuery Code. What I want to do is I want to empty the `am-container` but I am unable to do so.

```
jQuery(document).find("div[id='am-container']").html('');
```

and following is my HTML structure.

```
<div class="mid-part-right">
 <div class="match-image">
  <div class="main-gallary">
   <div class="container">
    <div id="am-container" class="am-container">
     <a class="draggable am-wrapper" href="#" style="width: 233px; height: 133px; margin: 2px;">
     <a class="draggable am-wrapper" href="#" style="width: 233px; height: 133px; margin: 2px;">
<a class="draggable am-wrapper" href="#" style="width: 263px; height: 133px; margin: 2px;">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here's a complete code snippet:

```js
jQuery(document).find("div[id='am-container']").html('');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mid-part-right">
  <div class="match-image">
    <div class="main-gallary">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="am-container" class="am-container">
          <a class="draggable am-wrapper" href="#" style="width: 233px; height: 133px; margin: 2px;">
            <a class="draggable am-wrapper" href="#" style="width: 233px; height: 133px; margin: 2px;">
              <a class="draggable am-wrapper" href="#" style="width: 263px; height: 133px; margin: 2px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not simple `$('#am-container').html('');` ?

Comment: `$('#am-container').empty();`

Comment: Do you have duplicate ID's? If so don't, IDs must be unique. Your code will most likley work then. Works fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/urqAu/1/

Comment: Your links aren't closed.

Comment: With the `a` tags closed, your current code works: http://jsfiddle.net/QE5YX/. Though `$('#am-container')` is all you need to select the element.

Comment: any reason for down vote?

Comment: @JasonP: i tried your fiddle but it is not working

Comment: @noobie-php It works for me. What about it isn't working?

Comment: @JasonP: The elements still exits, and that was the core reason i went for `document`

Comment: @noobie-php In that case, you don't want to "empty the `am-container`", you want to **remove** it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to remove the element `am-container` not what it contains, try this

```
$('#am-container').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('#am-container').html('');
```

Or

```
$('#am-container').empty();
```

If you want to ***remove*** the container and its children, use:

```
$('#am-container').remove();
```

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6YMpb/. Provided you close your anchor tags.

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery('#am-container').html('');
```

Try this one :

```
$("#am-container").children().text(""); 


$("div#am-container a").each(function(el){$(el).empty();});
```

Comment: @noobie-php : Did you got the output. Please check the last updated line.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use like

```
$("#am-container").empty();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to remove the element you're trying to select:

```
$('#am-container').remove();
```

Comment: Well your answer was almost identical, but i marked correct for the 1 that is shown 1st in my list